# path planning with a two-wheeled robot

Tags: ros, simulation, rviz, kalman, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I am currently using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

```
   My aim is to simulate a 2-wheeled robot in an potentially slippery environment, depending on where the robot actually is.

   To do so, I have made a 2D model working in Matlab, I followed every ROS tutorials on the ROS Wiki.
```

1)I tried to make a really simple .urdf file (a 4-wheeled box found on github), but it won't be parsed in xml, because               ROS can't find the urdfdom package. I checked and indeed I can't find it in the ROS repository...What should I do?

2. There is a closed-loop control in Matlab, and a Kalman filter to use the signal of a gyroscope efficiently and know how to react when there is slip. Should I create a node for each Matlab script? How should I synchronize the Twist messages (which is not a problem in Matlab)?

I know it is a big question,but it would really be enlighting to me. I struggled with Jade and went back to Indigo, since it is more documented.

Thanks for taking time to read this long post.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213144/path-planning-with-a-two-wheeled-robot/) by [Cookie132](https://answers.ros.org/users/23099/cookie132/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

about 1) `sudo apt-get install liburdfdom-dev` should help ([see wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/urdfdom)).

about 2) can you please provide some more information? I'm not sure what you actually try to achieve. Are you using rosmatlab (or something similar)? Do you want to port the matlab code to C++?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0